# LibreOffice Command Line Open Docx File, On Linux

Tags: python, shell, command-line, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I need to open Docx file using LibreOffice in command line mode.

```
libreoffice6.0 -o [filename].docx
```

Then..
[image]

This command is running in script, I can't handle the confirm window. So is it possible to open document directly ?

Comment: What do you need to do to this document after opening it?

Comment: Just open. Maybe it's odd :)